# Spark: How to start remotely Jupyter in 'yarn_client' mode from a different user

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, jupyter

Let's assume I've got a 4 nodes Hadoop cluster (Cloudera distro in my case) with a user named 'hadoop' on each node ('/home/hadoop'). Also, I've got a fifth server with installed on it, Jupyter and Anaconda with a user named 'ipython', but without hadoop installation.

Let's say I want to start Jupyter remotely from that fifth server in 'yarn_client' mode by keeping the 'ipython' user, my problem is that I've got an issue from logs which says that the user 'ipython' isn't allowed (or something like that).

For info I copied-paste a dummy directory (to set the HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable) from the Hadoop cluster to that fifth server. Everything works well with the 'local[*]' setting in my 'kernel.json' file (fortunately), but the issue appears back when I change the master value into 'yarn_client' (unfortunately)...

Is there a trick to solve that issue ? Or maybe several different tricks ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working deployment of CDH5.5 + jupyter with pyspark and scala native spark. In my case I am using a dedicated user to start a jupyter server and then connecting to it from a client browser.

Before sharing some thoughts about your problem I would like to point out that if your fifth server is not close connected to your cluster you should avoid launching pyspark in *yarn-client* mode, as the communication latency would surely slow your jobs. As far as I know *yarn-cluster* mode cannot be invoked remotely without `pyspark-submit`

If you still want your driver node to be executing in that 5th server, make sure that your user "ipython" has the correct permission to access hdfs and other hadoop conf directories, you might need to create that user in your other hadoop nodes.

Also make sure that your yarn-conf.xml is correctly configured to reflect the address of your yarn ResourceManager.